# Efficient way to deserialize polymorphic wrapper classes in Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have to use a custom deserializer in order to parse a wrapping class (think of it as an Either).
The only way I've been able to figure out which contained type to parse into is by first parsing the json as a ObjectNode using ObjectMapper.readTree() and then evaluating on a field. Basically doing the same as in example 6 here: http://programmerbruce.blogspot.se/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html

I have a gut feeling that this is not the best performance wise as I'm effectively parsing the section within the wrapping class twice, but it would be interesting to hear if:

- there is a better option?
- readTree is lazy or eager, meaning that I can just ignore the fact that I'm parsing twice?

  ```
  public class EitherResponseJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<EitherResponse<IdTypeResponse, ErrorIdTypeResponse>> implements ContextualDeserializer {

      protected JavaType successType;
      protected JavaType errorType;

      @Override
      public EitherResponse<IdTypeResponse, ErrorIdTypeResponse> deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException     {
          ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) jp.getCodec();
          ObjectNode root = mapper.readTree(jp);

          if(root.get("error") == null){
              return new EitherResponse<>((IdTypeResponse) mapper.treeToValue(root, successType.getRawClass()));
          }

          return new EitherResponse<>((ErrorIdTypeResponse) mapper.treeToValue(root, errorType.getRawClass()));
      }

      @Override
      public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(DeserializationContext ctxt, BeanProperty property) throws JsonMappingException {
          final JavaType contextualType = ctxt.getContextualType();
          final JavaType successType = contextualType.containedType(0);
          final JavaType errorType = contextualType.containedType(1);
          EitherResponseJsonDeserializer deserializer = new EitherResponseJsonDeserializer();
          deserializer.successType = successType;
          deserializer.errorType = errorType;
          return deserializer;
      }
  }
  ```